# how can I check the excel sheet and pdf file size in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here is my code -

```
file_name = "#{downloaded_file_name}_#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}.pdf"

result, pdf_report = ReportFullStores.get_order_receipts(customer, input_data)
#call method
schedule_report.generate_schedule_report(file_name, pdf_report)

#here before sending the file into mailer I want to check the file size.

# If file size is greater than 20 mb
  #code here  
# else
  #code here
#end
```

#### -> this is the method which is saving the file into folder I need to read the size of the file under this folder.

```
#save file in public/scheduled_reports folder xls / pdf or both
def generate_schedule_report(file_name, report_data)
  #then save file to public folder
  save_path = Rails.root.join('public/scheduled_reports',file_name)
  File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
    file << report_data
  end
end
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-i-size gives the size in *bytes*, so convert it to *mb* .. very easy

Comment: len_in_bytes = File.size("file_name") now how can I convert it into mb?

Comment: What is the problem now ?

Comment: see I am converting the byte data into mb like - require 'action_view',include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper ,number_to_human_size(29696). And I am looking, Is there any simpler way to do that so that I can easily check that if data is more than 20 mb?

Comment: What about `File.size("file_name") > 20.megabytes`?

Comment: @Tiago, File.size("file_name") will give u size in byte. first we need to convert it into mb then will do comparison.

Comment: @Chitra: You're right, `File.size` returns the size in bytes. `20.megabytes` (an [ActiveSupport method](http://apidock.com/rails/Numeric/megabytes)) also returns a size in bytes. (i.e. `20*1024*1024`, or `20971520`). A comparison between two bytes amounts will give the expected result. Or, if you really want to compare two MB values, just divide `File.size` by `1048576.0` and compare it to `20.0`.